# Unable to open file in 'r' mode

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I'm trying to read from a text file in my synthesis code. However, I get an error when I try to open a file that does exist.

I have tried placing the text file in various folders because I figured the problem was that the program is unable to find the text file. None of these different positions have worked.

```
type chunk is array (INPUTNUM downto 0) of std_logic_vector (WIDTH-1 downto 0);

       impure function ReadfromFile (FileName: in string) return chunk is
           FILE IN_FILE : text open read_mode is FileName;
           variable BUFF : line;
           variable val : chunk;
       begin
           for i in 0 to INPUTNUM loop
               readline (IN_FILE, BUFF);
               read (BUFF, val(i));
           end loop;
       return val;
       end function;

signal w : chunk  := ReadfromFile("neuron_text.txt");
```

I expected the file to be read and the values to be stored in the w signal. However, when I run the RTL analysis I get the error : "[Synth 8-3302] unable to open file 'neuron_text.txt' in 'r' mode" as well as "[Synth 8-421] mismatched array sizes in rhs and lhs of assignment". I assume the second error is a result of the first one though.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. The first error is because the file isn't found. The second is because the file isn't open and you are obliviously reading lines from it.  See [Vivado (2016.2) file I/O support - std.textio](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Vivado-2016-2-file-I-O-support-std-textio/td-p/788089) for example.

Comment: I've answered your question, but I have also voted to close it, because it is not about programming. (It's about how to use Vivado.)

Answer (score 1):

Vivado runs four, five or six levels of hierarchy lower down than you think (depending on the version you're running). Try:

```
signal w : chunk  := ReadfromFile("../../../../neuron_text.txt");
```

or

```
signal w : chunk  := ReadfromFile("../../../../../neuron_text.txt");
```

or even

```
signal w : chunk  := ReadfromFile("../../../../../../neuron_text.txt");
```

If this still doesn't work, try opening a file for writing, seeing where it gets creating and using that information to your advantage.